# How to create the Spotify layout with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to replicate the main layout of **Spotify**, however, I have two problems, which are:

1. I am not able to place the two **containers(Blue and Red)** to be the
   ideal `height`.
2. I am not able to put the **Container(Yellow)** to be at the `bottom`.

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  height: 91px;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="red">red</div>
  <div class="yellow">yellow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's you ideal height? Use `align-self` instead of `justify-content` for the footer.

Comment: The ideal is the same as the Spotify layout itself, remembering that the three containers must have position: relative. I've used all aligns and justify, but nothing fits the context I need, do the test and try to see what I'm saying.

Comment: I did the test: https://nimb.ws/CyxDWc